# Where to put await in an async method in this specific scenario

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency

I was dicussing this with a colleague, and none of us were sure about it. Given these two methods using the asynchronous framework in C#, will there be a difference in performance between the two?

```
public async Task<ReadRespone> MethodA(ReadRequest request)
{
    var response = SynchronousReadThatTakesAWhileToExecute();
    return await Task.FromResult(new ReadResponse(response));
}

public async Task<ReadResponse> MethodB(ReadRequest request)
{
    var response = await Task.FromResult(SynchronousReadThatTakesAWhileToExecute());
    return new ReadResponse(response);
}
```

I was thinking that MethodA would perform the slow method syncronously, and then, since it only uses await for a trivial constructor, would in practice be a synchronous method, which would block execution for other threads. My colleague argued that both would be the same in practice, and that an async method should always return a task (but I'm thinking that await already "unboxes" the Task, and that an asynch method only needs to have an await Task somewhere in it to be correct).

Thanks

Comment: You want Task.Run() instead of Task.FromResult()

Comment: `Task.FromResult` returns a **completed** task. Awaiting it will therefore not really be asynchronous.

Comment: Obligatory comment: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Second four run your horses and in addition: look at the respective lowered codes. I wouldn't be surprised if they were optimized to look nearly the same.

Comment: It's a complete waste of time to do `await Task.FromResult`. It's like doing `x = x + 1 - 1;`.

Comment: Yes, .fromResult was wrong, we've changed it to Task.Run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `Task.FromResult()` doesn't really work like that. It takes a value and returns a completed task, with the value. You want to use `Task.Run` or `TaskFactory.StartNew`.

```cs
public async Task<ReadResponse> Foo(ReadRequest request)
{
    var result = await Task.Run(SynchronousReadThatTakesAWhileToExecute);
    return new ReadResponse(result);
}
```

Notice the lack of brackes after `SynchronousReadThatTakesAWhileToExecute`. This is because I am not calling the function directly but passing it to `Task.Run` instead. This is functionally equivalent to passing `() => SynchronousReadThatTakesAWhileToExecute()` to `Task.Run` as an argument.

Editing my response so that it actually answers the question:
The provided two options are pretty much identical performance-wise.

Comment: Your `Task.Run` advice violates the recommendation in this article: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/).

Comment: Thank you. I'm assuming that when using Task.Run instead, they are still equivalent?

Comment: Well, isn't it also a matter of context. In the scenario described the result is immediately after returned. So won't the thread wait for the result and thus the end result is synchronous anyway ?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I feel like this article is specifically about writing APIs and libraries. It makes some valid points and it was an interesting read.

Quote from the article:
"If a developer needs to achieve responsiveness or parallelism with synchronous APIs, they can simply wrap the invocation with a method like Task.Run." - I think this is the description that applies to the current situation.

Comment: @fabikaktus I'm not sure what exactly you mean. The key thing is that I am not calling SynchronousReadThatTakesAWhileToExecute in my code directly, only passing it to a new task. (Either by using a lambda or method group)

Comment: My understanding of Stephen Toub's [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) is that the `Foo` should be a synchronous method (should have `ReadResponse` return type), and the caller can invoke it asynchronously with `await Task.Run(() => Foo(request))`. In other words the `Task.Run` should be used at the last possible moment. The article is about libraries, but also about "library-like" code in general, even if it's located in the presentation tier. At least this is my interpretation.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I think you are right. Writing an async wrapper like this *feels* like the right thing to do but it might just be redundant indeed...

Answer (score 2):

Your colleague is right. The `MethodA` and `MethodB` are practically equivalent. They are both asynchronous facades with synchronous implementations. Every time these methods are called, the calling thread does all the work, and then is handed back an already completed task (`.IsCompleted == true`). The task contains either the result or an exception. The [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) keyword only helps at simplifying the result/exception wrapping. You could implement exactly the same behavior without `async`, with a little more code:

```
public Task<ReadResponse> MethodC(ReadRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var response = SynchronousReadThatTakesAWhileToExecute();
        return Task.FromResult(new ReadResponse(response));
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
    {
        return Task.FromCanceled<ReadResponse>(oce.CancellationToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Task.FromException<ReadResponse>(ex);
    }
}
```

The non-`async` method `MethodC` is intended for educational/demonstration purposes (it has a hidden bag). In practice using `async` for the wrapping is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, there's practically no difference between those methods.

However, both methods are fully synchronous even though they have an asynchronous signature. I do not recommend this, since it will be confusing to anyone using this code.

If you *can* make it asynchronous, then do so:

```
public async Task<ReadRespone> MethodAsync(ReadRequest request)
{
  var response = await AsynchronousReadThatTakesAWhileToExecuteAsync();
  return new ReadResponse(response);
}
```

If the work is just synchronous (and you can't make it asynchronous), then make your method synchronous:

```
public ReadRespone Method(ReadRequest request)
{
  var response = SynchronousReadThatTakesAWhileToExecute();
  return new ReadResponse(response);
}
```

If you have synchronous work (and you can't make it asynchronous), and your method must be asynchronous (i.e., it's implementing an interface method), then you can make a synchronous implementation of an asynchronous interface. Note that this code runs synchronously, which is surprising to consumers, so I recommend documenting the possibly-synchronous nature in the interface docs itself.

```
#pragma warning disable 1998
public async Task<ReadRespone> MethodAsync(ReadRequest request)
#pragma warning restore 1998
{
  var response = SynchronousReadThatTakesAWhileToExecute();
  return new ReadResponse(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are basically the same. Both will perform blocking work without giving the control back to the calling method. [Async state machine](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) generated by compiler will "shortcut" if the task has already finished and actually will continue executing the current method. This can be demonstrated with the following code:

```cs
async Task FakeAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before IN FakeAsync");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
    Thread.Sleep(500); // "simulate" CPU-bound work
    Console.WriteLine("After IN FakeAsync");
}

async Task RealAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before IN RealAsync");
    await Task.Yield();
    Thread.Sleep(500); // "simulate" CPU-bound work
    Console.WriteLine("After IN RealAsync");
}

Console.WriteLine("Before FakeAsync");
var task =  FakeAsync();
Console.WriteLine("After FakeAsync");
await task;
Console.WriteLine("After await FakeAsync");
Console.WriteLine("---------");
Console.WriteLine("Before RealAsync");
var task1 = RealAsync();
Console.WriteLine("After RealAsync");
await task1;
Console.WriteLine("After await RealAsync");
```

Which will give the following output:

```
Before FakeAsync
Before IN FakeAsync
After IN FakeAsync
After FakeAsync
After await FakeAsync
---------
Before RealAsync
Before IN RealAsync
After RealAsync
After IN RealAsync
After await RealAsync
```

Note that for the `FakeAsync` both "IN" statements are executed before the rest of the calling method, while for the `RealAsync` the control is given back to the calling method (hence the "After RealAsync" between the "IN"s)

Aslo bear in mind that [`Task.Yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield?view=net-7.0) trick will work when no synchronization context is present so it can be used for some test scenarios, for "real life" the better approach is [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-8.0):

```cs
async Task RealAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before IN RealAsync");
    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(500)); // "simulate" CPU-bound work)
    Console.WriteLine("After IN RealAsync");
}
```

Read more:

- [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) documentation
- [Asynchronous Programming in .NET - Introduction, Misconceptions, and Problems](https://wapplegate.com/asynchronous-programming/)
- [Threading in C#](https://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joseph Albahari (a bit dated but still amazing)